# Is there a way how to suppress pango console warning?

Tags: console, warnings, pango

Pango is producing number of useless messages to console for common user.
E.g.

> text2image --list_available_fonts

produces huge number of lines like this:

```
(process:24244): Pango-CRITICAL **: 13:07:20.751: pango_font_description_set_size: assertion 'size >= 0' failed
424: Schumacher Clean Medium

(process:24244): Pango-CRITICAL **: 13:07:20.792: pango_font_description_set_size: assertion 'size >= 0' failed
425: Schumacher Clean Wide Bold

(process:24244): Pango-CRITICAL **: 13:07:20.836: pango_font_description_set_size: assertion 'size >= 0' failed
426: Schumacher Clean Wide Medium

(process:24244): Pango-CRITICAL **: 13:07:20.875: pango_font_description_set_size: assertion 'size >= 0' failed
427: Schumacher Clean Wide Medium Italic

(process:24244): Pango-CRITICAL **: 13:07:20.920: pango_font_description_set_size: assertion 'size >= 0' failed
```

[text2image](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/60fd2b4abaa9c5c5c42d32db57576bc95d28a78a/doc/text2image.1.asc) is tesseract tool for render text file to image.

Is it possible to hide this kind of information?